# Refresh webpage if got connection time out selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, exception, timeout

I am using proxies rotating and sometimes it could happen one of these randomly doesn't work and I get `"ERR_TIMED_OUT"` enable to reach server and script just crashed without continuing, is it possible to refresh the webpage automatically in silenium when this happens (so the proxy will rotate). I thought about catch exception putting then `driver.refresh()` but how can I catch into the entire code without try- except for every instruction? is there another solution? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use event_firing_webdriver:
https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.event_firing_webdriver.html

you can decorate method get() and execute try except there (with refresh on timeout exception).